# How is foliation of manifolds' theory useful in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am interested on getting some hints on how [Foliations Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) of Manifolds can be used fruitfully on General Relativity. I just started my Ph.D on Mathematics this semester focusing on studying Holomorphic foliations on projective manifolds.

Comment: Look at Sean Carol's note's linked in this question. This is one example when foliation of manifolds can be used to guess the form of a metric using the Frobenius theorem:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83693/

Comment: You may be interested in globally hyperbolic manifolds and initial value problem in general relativity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll elaborate on the things mentioned in the comments. That being said, this will refer mostly to very specific foliations and not much of a general theory.

First, since manifolds in GR have a timelike and a spacelike component, it's always worth keeping track of those. Then foliations arise very naturally trying to see whether or not there is a reasonable initial value problem formulation for the Einstein field equations. To see this, consider that they usually come in 4-dimensional notation
$$ G_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu},$$
which can be derived from varying the corresponding Einstein-Hilbert action w.r.t. $g_{\mu\nu}$
$$S= \int_V \mathrm{d}^4x \sqrt{-g} \frac{\kappa}{2} \{ R +\mathcal{L}  \} + \int_{\partial V} \text{stuff}, $$
$R$ being the Ricci scalar, $\mathcal{L}$ the Lagrangian density for matter (and cosmological constant $\Lambda$), $g$ the determinant of the metric - the boundary terms I alluded to, but the details are slightly messy, don't help much, but nevertheless I think that as a mathematician you like seeing that they still play a role in principle.

The term initial value formulation already tells the source of possible problems: "Initial" hints at time and the usual 4D version mixes those up heavily. Now the foliation comes in: We can find an initial value formulation (and a Hamiltonian density formulation) as long as the manifold proves to be [globally hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold). The technical definition (as found on Wikipedia in the link) boils down to the ability to find, in a sense, that the manifold can be decomposed as
$$ \mathbb{R}\times M_3, $$
for some three-manifolds $M_3$ and the real line basically giving the time direction. The leaves of the foliation are more or less and very roughly equal-time hypersurfaces.

Second, you can consider different kinds of foliations, as well. One example would be to separate a certain notion of time of the space part (say, $S_1\times M_3$). The other certain geometric parts within the 3-manifold - like separating out the spherically symmetric part as two-sphere leaves, giving rise to the quite ubiquitous $\mathrm{d} \Omega$ in line elements.

Skimming through the tables of contents and indices of the books by [Choquet-Bruhat](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=UjHbm5rfpi8C&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Hawking & Ellis](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=QagG_KI7Ll8C&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Beem, Ehrlich & Easley](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=N9v-F0VRQR0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [O'Neill](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=CGk1eRSjFIIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false), however, I couldn't find hints at a very general theory of this (fibre, leaf, foliation are not in the indices). The best I could come up with is one very specific type of foliation that can usually be found in many textbooks (e.g. [Gourgoulhon](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035) (linked the version on the arxiv)) called the 3+1-decomposition needed for initial value formulations and therefore most of the work on numerical relativity. Of course, that still leaves a bit of a choice how to do this particular foliation, but it's already very focussed on a certain application and maybe not as general as you might be interested in. Still, Gourgoulhon's book/lecture notes has a lot to offer from an applied point of view.

[This book by Reinhart](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=SVPxCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) offers some references to different applications in technical papers. Still, as far as I could tell, specific foliations for certain metrics, and a lot to the above mentioned problems.